# is it possible to instantiate a layout based on it's name?

Tags: android, layout

I would like to create a framework that "builds" part of the application structure and presentation views at runtime, parsing some configuration file.
What I'm wondering is if there's a way in with I can reference a layout and instantiate it based on a name without creating a map.
for example instead out using simply:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewWithId(R.id.layout1);
```

Doing something more like:

```
String name = Config.getLayout1();  
ViewGroup layout = getLayoutByName(name);
```

Comment: see `Resources#getIdentifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get layout by `R.id.layout1` it actually first gets it's resource ID and pass it to `findViewWithID`.

So you can find that ID yourself and send that to `findViewWithId` function.

You can do something like this:

```
String layoutName = "layout1";
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(layoutName, "layout", context.getPackageName());
```

Then get the actual view:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewWithId(resID);
```